# VB6 grid with expandible / collapsible rows

Tags: datagrid, vb6

I'm looking for a grid for VB6 (Yes, VB6 in 2016!) capable of displaying "multiline rows" and expand them with [+] and collapse them with [-]. I know there are controls in old sites but some sites like VBAccelerator are gone. 
Preferably free...

I still have a Flexgrid control, not sure if that would be useful for that purposes.

Comment: The MSHFlexGrid can do this when bound to hierarchical Recordsets.  This includes fabricated Recordsets so the feature's use doesn't require an external OLEDB or MSDASQL-shimmed ODBC datasource of any kind.

Comment: Perhaps that MSHFlexGrid is what I looking for, any examples would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I just found this [AbsGrid](http://xout.free.fr/agrid/index.php) based on the popular SGrid 2.